# Android - the following class could not be found

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating bottom menu in my android app

I have created on directory in `res/menu/option_menu.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <item android:id="@+id/post_offer"
        android:title="postoffer"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/history"
        android:title="history"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/inbox"
        android:title="inbox"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:title="notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/people"
        android:title="people"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</menu>
```

then I included this xml in activity_main.xml and java

```
<include
        layout="@menu/option_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

and this java

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        //MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        //inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
        //return true;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.post_offer:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Now problem is when I try to check my activity_main.xml in design mode it showing this following error

**Missing Classes**

The following classes could not be found:

-Item (Fix build path, Edit XML)

-Menu(Fix build path, Edit XML)

**EDIT**

I am using

Compile SDK version:  API 25:Android 7.1.1(Nougat)

Build Tool version: 25.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then I included this xml in activity_main.xml and java

You shouldn't do that. Just leave the `menu` xml layout as is and inflate it as you did in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. It should work.

Comment: Yes it works! but it goes in the top menu. I want these menus in the bottom

Comment: Then you are in wrong direction. You should use [`BottonNavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) which is entirely different component.

Comment: Well I was referring to this article https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implement-an-options-menu--mobile-9453   ... let me try what you said @BottonNavigationView

Comment: BottonNavigationView works fine!. Thank you     update your answer

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot see anything related to `BottomNavigationView` in your question. Answering "`BottomNavigationView`" would mislead other users who may later see this post.

Comment: Update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the `<include>` tags works only for layout XML (ones that extend `View` but a menu certainly does not do that)